# How to combine lists/arrays during a loop without iterating through entire array? Goal of reducing computation time

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, time-complexity

If I have an array of arrays like this:

```
n = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[1,6],[4,7],[8,9],[6,8]]
```

What I want to do is iterate through this and combine all arrays that have at least one element in common, so the end result would be:

```
[[1,2,3,6,8,9],[4,5,7]]
```

The dataset has about *4 million arrays*, each ranging in size from *0-1000* elements. What I do not want to do is iterate over the 4 million arrays multiple times. I'm trying to find the fastest way to do this.

What I thought of doing is iterating through array n and checking if the first and second arrays have a matching element. If they do, merge them into a set and keep doing this until you get to an array that does not share an element. Then create a new set with this different array and repeat. And AFTER that, when we come to an array that has a shared element with any one of the new sets, it will be added to it, WITHOUT iterating through the whole original 4 million array n. Here's as far as I got:

```
final_list = []
for i in range(0, len(n)-1):
    inter_list = list(set(inter_list))
    if (n[i].ravel()[:,None] == n[i+1].ravel()).any():
        inter_list.append(np.concatenate((DF_list[i], DF_list[i+1]), axis=0))
    final_list.append(inter_list)
```

And here's where I got lost, instead of going back to iterating through the entire array n, I want to check the next arrays with the new `final_list`.

Or if you know of any other methods to reduce the computational complexity of this problem overall? I've been trying to use the *Dask Library* but I cannot seem to get it below *O(n^2)* or if it cannot be reduced, somehow parallelizing this task to increase speed.

EDIT: I have tried the methods from the suggested similar threads, but all of them are still pretty slow. I was hoping for a faster way to do it. Also, the networkx method and the array loop method gave different results, no idea why. One was ~1400 in length for the first combo and the other ~1250.

Comment: what would happen if `n` were `[..., [6,8]]`?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that scenario. It would combine [1,2,3,6], [8,9] and [6,8] and the end result would be [1,2,3,6,8,9]. So basically everything gets combined if there's some shared element anywhere.

Comment: is it right to say that you have millions of `n` each containing 1000 of edges and that you are looking for the connected components?

Comment: I think this question  [Combining lists with overlapping elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567089/combining-lists-with-overlapping-elements) is similar, I m not sure about the complexity

Comment: @cards n has millions or arrays, each containing 1000 or so of edges yeah. If connected components means every array that shares at least one similar element, then yeah.

Comment: then maybe using some add hoc library could a small step forward, give a try to [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) and compare the performance with just some of the arrays

Comment: @cards I've also converted the arrays from numpy to dask arrays, to see if the dask library will help. Can you use these with networkx?

Comment: no idea about _dask_, sorry

Comment: Your result has lists that differ in length.  That suggests that a 'vectorized' `numpy` result is not possible.  The result can't be expressed as a multidimensional array.  There are a lot of duplicates, but all use iteration on lists.  (`numpy without-loops actually just moves the loops into compiled code.)